# Django user hierarchy

Tags: django, panel, admin, hierarchy

I'm to make a web app that will implement something like user hierarchy. I would like to do it like this:
1. Superuser makes users (with some permissions), who can also add users (only with permissions which they own). This users can also add users, and so on. No one should be able to edit users who have more permissions.

The thing is that I want to make Django Admin Panel avaliable for all of these users. Is it even possible to make such thing? I've searched the web and didn't find solution. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create your own views for adding users if you want to control the created users' permissions. On the Django admin site, any user that can create users can create superusers.

From the Django docs on [creating users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#creating-users):

> If you want your own user account to be able to create users using the Django admin site, you'll need to give yourself permission to add users and change users (i.e., the "Add user" and "Change user" permissions). If your account has permission to add users but not to change them, you won't be able to add users. Why? Because if you have permission to add users, you have the power to create superusers, which can then, in turn, change other users. So Django requires add and change permissions as a slight security measure.

Answer (score 2):

Every user who'll need access to the admin must have the `is_staff=True` flag. It's *never* a good idea to allow users not associated with your organization access to the admin. Seriously, just don't do it. If that's your plan, find another.

That said, it can be done, but it's not for the faint of heart. There's a lot involved. First subclass the default `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm` (Auth uses two separate forms for it's admin). Override the `__init__` method of each to pull out the `request` from `kwargs` (Forms don't get the request by default, but it's necessary here, so you have to do a bit of a workaround.) Then, subclass the default `UserAdmin`, set `form` and `add_form` to the new forms and override `get_form` (to pass in `request`) and each of the `has_foo_permission` methods to limit access. The `queryset` method also needs to be overrode so users only see users they can modify in the admin.

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        pass

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)

        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Limit groups and permissions to those that belong to current user
        if self.request and not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields['groups'].queryset = self.request.user.groups.all()
            self.fields['user_permissions'].queryset = self.request.user.user_permissions.all()

 class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        pass

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)

        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Limit groups and permissions to those that belong to current user
        if self.request and not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields['groups'].queryset = self.request.user.groups.all()
            self.fields['user_permissions'].queryset = self.request.user.user_permissions.all()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    limited_fieldsets = ( # Copied from default `UserAdmin`, but removed `is_superuser`
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (_('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets
        elif not request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.limited_fieldsets
        else:
            return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """Return a metaclass that will automatically pass `request` kwarg into the form"""
        ModelForm = super(LinkAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        class ModelFormMetaClass(ModelForm):
            def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                kwargs['request'] = request
                return ModelForm(*args, **kwargs)
        return ModelFormMetaClass

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        """
        If not superuser only allow add if the current user has at least some
        groups or permissions. (they'll have to be able to at least have something
        to assign the user they are creating).
        """
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            if not request.user.groups.exists() or not request.user.user_permissions.exist():
                return False

        return True


    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        If not superuser, current user can only modify users who have a subset of the
        groups and permissions they have.
        """

        if obj and not request.user.is_superuser:
            # Check that all of the object's groups are in the current user's groups
            user_groups = list(request.user.groups.all())
            for group in obj.groups.all():
                try:
                    user_groups.index(group)
                except ValueError:
                    return False

            # Check that all of the object's permissions are in the current user's permissions
            user_permissions = list(request.user.user_permissions.all())
            for permission in obj.user_permissions.all():
                try:
                    user_permissions.index(permission)
                except ValueError:
                    return False

        return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        """Same logic as `has_change_permission`"""
        return self.has_change_permission(request, obj)

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CustomUserAdmin, self).queryset(self, request)

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            """
            This part is a little counter-intuitive. We're going to first get a
            list of all groups/permissions that don't belong to the user, and
            then use that to exclude users that do have those from the queryset.
            """

            user_group_pks = [g.pk for g request.user.groups.values('pk')]
            exclude_groups = Group.objects.exclude(pk__in=user_group_pks)

            user_permission_pks = [p.pk for p in request.user.user_permissions.values('pk')]
            exclude_permissions = Permission.objects.exclude(pk__in=user_permission_pks)

            return qs.exclude(groups__in=exclude_groups, user_permissions__in=exclude_permissions)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: I may have misread the code, but you don't seem to have prevented users from setting the superuser flag.

Comment: Haha. Yeah, I should add that in too. The code was such a herculean effort to begin with, I knew I'd miss something. Whether or not this should ever actually be used is debatable, but it *can* be done, so I wanted to try it ;).

Answer (score 1):

Django contains a inbuilt system for maintaining User Hierarchy - Django-RBAC.

RBAC stands for ***Role Based Access Control***. Its a mechanism for creating and managing permission based on hierarchy. You just need to study this a bit.